# substring query in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want a write following query.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month FROM (`tblsales_month`)
```

So i wrote following code.

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month')
        ->from('tblsales_month');
```

But it generate following query with unnecessary back quote.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(zsmonth, `5`, `2)` as month FROM (`tblsales_month`)
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add second parameter `FALSE`, like:

```
$this->db->select('SUBSTRING(zsmonth, 5, 2) as month', FALSE)
        ->from('tblsales_month');
```

Setting second parameter to `FALSE`, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.