# Adding a substring in a CodeIgniter Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to add a substring in an active query?

I have this example that works when I write it out in pure sql. However, when I write it in an active query in CI, the results don't show. I was wondering if someone can help verify if this is correct.

```
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('user_table.id','user_table.first_name','user_table.last_name','user_table.email','user_table.created_on');
        $this->db->from($this->user_table);
        $this->db->join($this->account_items_table,'user_accounts.id = account_items.user_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->where('SUBSTRING(account_items.key,1,2)',$input);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486162/substring-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: Include the values of `$this->user_column_order` , `$this->user_table`,`$this->account_items_table` in your question

Comment: account_items only uses the user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Probably CI is adding backticks around your expression pass third argument as false in `where()`

```
$this->db->where('SUBSTRING(account_items.key,1,2)',$input,false);
```

Comment: @JianYA what do get when you run `echo $this->db->last_query();` after executing active record's query builder ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think i'll use another method instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
$this->db->where('SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1)=','H');
$query = $this->db->get('news');
print $this->db->last_query();
```

The only difference I can see is I have included the = operator.

As you can see it returns the article named "Hello":
https://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~in9352/codeigniter3/

And the SQL statement is: SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE SUBSTRING(title, 1, 1) = 'H'

As suggested you should use

```
print $this->db->last_query();
```

To see what YOUR SQL is... It allowed to spot the missing = operator in my case... debugging is always useful!